# How to show a bar while Loading routes on the top of the website?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do I show the loading bar on top of the website?

For example, when we go to youtube, and we click on any tab in there, a long white red loading progress bar pops on top of the screen. What methods can I use to implement it on my website as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an 
attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical 
problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result,
 we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt 
and what didn't work as expected. hint: You can use MUI [linear progress](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/#linear-indeterminate) to implement it in your website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this on React to show the progress bar https://www.npmjs.com/package/@badrap/bar-of-progress

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).